# Unity Giving following error : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: unity, c#

im going to probably look really stupid and i will be no means admit this is my code however i cant seems to get it to work so i was wondering you you might be able to?

I'm getting the following error when trying to break a block with the left click button in unity:
"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Player.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:67)"

the code that is causing the error is below:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mousePos, Vector2.zero);
            if (hit.collider.gameObject != null)
            {
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("hit nothing");
            }
        }
```

i've searched around for other ways to do this and after many itterations i cant seem to get it working still so i have come to the forms.

Sorry line 67 is: Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

i know it looks simular to other questions however i have looked at the link that was attached to this being a duplicate and i cant see anything in there that will help me so i am still stuck with the same issue.

Comment: We'll have a hard time guessing which line is line 67. You might want to highlight what line is line 67.

Comment: sorry the line 67 is:Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

Comment: And which of all of these objects is null?

Comment: @Josh I'm guessing you need to tag one of your cameras as 'MainCamera'. Check out Unity's scripting refernce [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html)

Comment: I'd agree with DrewAtWork that this is likely an issue with your camera setup. You can see this covered in the linked duplicate answer where it warns about: "Trying to use the result of a getter that's returning null...
/`/ main is null if no enabled cameras in the scene have the "MainCamera" tag`."